# Financial math, Compound Pound Interest help with steps?!

Tags: statistics

This is the question and below I have the answers but I don't understand how to get those answers.

You receive the following offers for the sale of your old home:

(a) $€\ 30 000$ on 31.12.17, $€\ 30 000$ on 31.12.20, $€\ 30 000$ on 31.12.

(b) $€\ 20 000$ on 31.12.17, $€\ 25 000$ on 31.12.18, $€\ 45 000$ on 31.12.23

Which offer is best for the seller (compound interest at $r=6\%$)?

Answers:

(a) $PVA = €\ 76337.39$

(b) $PVB = €\ 75308.13$

Comment: The last piece of data in offer (a) appears to be missing the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a) 
$$PVA = \frac{30000\cdot 1.06^6+30000\cdot 1.06^3 + 30000}{1.06^6} = 76337.39$$